# Im using ssh2_exec functionin php why it doesn't pass more then 3 parameters?

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

Why the `ssh2_exec` function doesn't pass more than three parameters?

```
$stream_1 = ssh2_exec($ssh, "/root/Script/Auto_Traces/show_ng_trace.sh $a $b $c $d $e");
```

In this case only `$a` `$b` `$c` are passing but not `$d` and `$e`, how can I solve it?

Comment: Test it out. print_r("/root/Script/Auto_Traces/show_ng_trace.sh $a $b $c $d $e"); Do you get what you expect?

Comment: i am not understend your point but im sure that only $a $b $c are passing...

Comment: Do $d and $e have values? Are they stings? Do they have spaces in them? have you turned on debugging to know what you are sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are spaces in some of the first 3 variables, so they're being treated as multiple arguments. Then the last 2 arguments are being ignored.
In case any of the variables have spaces (or other special characters) in them, you should escape them.

```
$ae = escapeshellarg($a);
$be = escapeshellarg($b);
// repeat for the rest of variables
$stream_1 = ssh2_exec($ssh, "/root/Script/Auto_Traces/show_ng_trace.sh $ae $be $ce $de $ee");
```